# initrd built with NFS module cannot mount NFS root

Tags: rhel, nfs, initrd, high-availability

I'm building a custom initrd so that I can boot diskless nodes with a tmpfs root rather than NFS root (a script in the initrd copies the contents of the root device to a tmpfs filesystem, then changes the value of `NEWROOT`). All seemed well and good in my test environment, I generated a custom initrd, booted it, / mounted from none as tmpfs but had all the files the NFS root provided, great stuff.

Then I started moving towards the real environment, and when the initrd boots it chokes trying to mount the NFS root (which is still a normal NFS boot at that point) complaining `mount.nfs4: No such device`.

I generate my initrd using:

```
dracut -v -m "nfs network base" --include rd.live.overlay/ / initrd-tmpfs.img
```

I confirmed that the `initrd-tmpfs.img` is being loaded (based on the early part of the PXE boot where it lists the initrd its loading).

When the initrd fails it drops into the emergency shell, and has a few interesting things:

`ip addr show` lists my IP from DHCP, and I can ping the NFS server

`echo $netroot` lists the NFS boot paramaters `nfs4:[Server IP]:[root location]:[nfs options]`

`mount -t nfs4 [Server IP]:[root location] /sysroot` results: `mount.nfs4: No such device` (very familiar)

`modprobe nfs` results: `modprobe:FATAL: Module nfs not found` obviously a problem

`grep nfs /usr/lib/dracut/modules.txt` does match

`grep nfs /usr/lib/modules/[kernel version]/modules.order` matches a few times, mentioning: `kernel/fs/nfs.ko | kernel/fs/nfsv3.ko | kernel/fs/nfsv4.ko` however none of these exist

Environment: RHEL 7

---

Looks like my question answered itself just as I finished writing it, I'll post the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last debugging step I did clued me in, so I figured I'd post the answer for the sake of others. `grep nfs /usr/lib/modules/[kernel version]/modules.order` matched `kernel/fs/nfs.ko | kernel/fs/nfsv3.ko | kernel/fs/nfsv4.ko`, but they didn't exist.

Well `*.ko` represents a kernel driver, and `initrd` has an option `--add-drivers`, so

```
dracut -v -m "nfs network base" --include rd.live.overlay/ / initrd-tmpfs.img
```

became:

```
dracut -v -m "nfs network base" --add-drivers "nfs nfsv4" \
--include rd.live.overlay/ / initrd-tmpfs.img
```

Then `lsinitrd | grep nfs` listed `nfs.ko` and `nfsv4.ko`, the root device got itself mounted, copied and happy days, there's a diskless server booted over NFS that has a tmpfs `/` directory, great stuff for a HA diskless cluster.

The difference in drivers between my test environment and target would be a result of `/etc/dracut.conf` or `/etc/dracut.conf.d/`, which can specify drivers to be included, but I didn't look into them too much (I would rather specify the drivers when running the command for the sake of my sanity).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write the answer!